# Is my solution for this differential equation correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this function: $$y''+4y= x-\cos(2x)$$
To proceed I calculated the associated homogeneous, after that I split the original equation into two parts, setting: $u(x) = x$ and $t(x)=-\cos(2x)$ to find two particular solutions. The final solution I've found is:
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos(2x)+c_2 \sin(2x)+\frac{1}{4}x -\frac{1}{4}x\sin(2x)$$
Did I any mistake?

Comment: Did you plug your solution into the equation and check it? By the way, what is sen?

Comment: The homogeneous equation is $y''+4y'=0$. The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2+4\lambda=0\implies \lambda=0\vee \lambda=-4$, i.e the homogeneous solution is $y=C_1+C_2e^{-4x}$. Should it be $y''+4y=x-\cos(2x)$?

Comment: Yes you're right the equation is $y''+4y=x-cos(2x)$

Comment: As Fabian suggested - did you check your solution by plugging it into the equation? Please notice that you can tag users using @username, so they will know you answered. BTW, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Galc127 thanks, but why if i give this equation to wolframealpha the solution that it finds is: $y(x) = c_2 sin(2 x) + c_1 cos(2 x) + x/4 + (sin^2(x))/8 - 1/4 x sin(2 x) - 1/8 cos^2(x)$

Comment: @andresca, ah, simple. $$\frac{\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{8}=-\frac{\cos(2x)}{8}$$ and you can redefine $c_1$ to be $c_1-\frac{1}{8}$.